# how to check if a product is repeated in shopping card in redux toolkit and react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I just made a shopping card with redux toolkit and reactJs. but I do not know how to handle the repetition of products in my shopping card. and It just add the same product several times!
how can I handle this?

shoppingCard.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";


// Create Slice
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingCard",
  initialState: { shoppingCardList: [], loading: true },
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
      const pseudoId = new Date().getTime(); //generating id for cart items
      state.shoppingCardList.push({
        id: pseudoId,
        productName: action.payload.product.name,
        productId: action.payload.product.product_code,
        quantity: action.payload.Quantity,
        price: parseInt(action.payload.product.price),
        totalPrice:
          action.payload.Quantity * parseInt(action.payload.product.forosh),
      });
      state.loading = false;
    },
    removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.shoppingCardList = state.shoppingCardList.filter(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id !== action.payload.cartItemId
      );
    },
  },
});
// console.log(slice);

// selectors
export const getShoppingCartItem = (state) => state.cart.shoppingCardList;

export const getTotalPrice = (state) => {
  return state.cart.shoppingCardList.reduce((total, shoppingCardList) => {
    return shoppingCardList.totalPrice + total;
  }, 0);
};

export const { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

shoppingCard.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import CardItem from "./shoppingCardItem";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addCommas } from "@persian-tools/persian-tools";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faArrowLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  getCartState,
  getShoppingCartItem,
  getTotalPrice,
} from "../store/shoppingcard";
import "../css/shoppingCard.css";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

const ShoppingCard = () => {
  const cartItem = useSelector(getShoppingCartItem);
  const total = useSelector(getTotalPrice);
  console.log("state shoppingCart", cartItem);
 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Card className="fixed-top">
        <Card.Body>
          <Link to="/nav/products">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} style={{ float: "left" }} />
          </Link>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <Loader
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          top: "50%",
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
          zIndex: "10",
        }}
        visible={state.loading === true ? true : false}
        type="Puff"
        color="#00BFFF"
        height={100}
        width={100}
      />
      <div style={{ height: "95vh", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <CardItem cartItem={cartItem} />
      </div>
      <Card className="fixed-bottom">
        <Card.Body>
          <div className="row">
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="col-6">
              مجموع : {addCommas(total)} ریال
            </div>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="col-6">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">ارسال سفارش</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ShoppingCard;
```

and the file of the shoppingCardItem is this.

shoppingCardItem.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "./icon";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { addCommas } from "@persian-tools/persian-tools";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeItemFromCart } from "../store/shoppingcard";

const CardItem = ({ cartItem }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {cartItem.map((cartItem) => (
        <Card className="shoppingCard" key={cartItem.productId}>
          <Card.Header>نام کالا : {cartItem.productName}</Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <div className="row" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
              <div className="col-8">
                <div className="row secondary">
                  قیمت پایه : {addCommas(cartItem.price)} ریال
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  تعداد کارتن سفارش شده :{cartItem.quantity}
                </div>
                <div className="row secondary">
                  مجموع : {addCommas(cartItem.totalPrice)} ریال
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-4">
                <img src="" alt="picture of products" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row m-2" style={{ float: "left" }}>
              <button style={{ width: "auto" }} className="btn btn-success m-2">
                +
              </button>
              <button style={{ width: "auto" }} className="btn btn-warning m-2">
                -
              </button>
              <button
                style={{ width: "auto" }}
                className="btn btn-danger m-2"
                onClick={() =>
                  dispatch(removeItemFromCart({ cartItemId: cartItem.id }))
                }
              >
                <Icon />
              </button>
            </div>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CardItem;
```

these are my redux and reactjs shopping card files.
I want to check if a product is already exist then just update the quantity number not adding another product with the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code I have added the logic in the shoppingCard.js component.
You can set your extra logic if you want.

```
     addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
        const pseudoId = new Date().getTime(); //generating id for cart items


        //Add logic for update the existing cart items start

        const existingCartItemIndex = state.shoppingCardList.findIndex(
            (item) => item.productId === action.item.productId
        );
        const existingCartItem = store.shoppingCardList[existingCartItemIndex];
        let updatedItems;

        if (existingCartItem) {
            //Find the index and update the items
            const updateItem = {
                ...existingCartItem,
                //extra code - add your logic
                quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + action.payload.quantity,
            }

            updatedItems = [...state.shoppingCardList]
            updatedItems[existingCartItemIndex] = updateItem;
        } else {
            const addObject = {
                id: pseudoId,
                productName: action.payload.product.name,
                productId: action.payload.product.product_code,
                quantity: action.payload.Quantity,
                price: parseInt(action.payload.product.price),
                totalPrice:
                    action.payload.Quantity * parseInt(action.payload.product.forosh),
            };
            //state.shoppingCardList.push(addObject);
            updatedItems = state.shoppingCardList.concat(addObject);
        }

        //Add logic for update the existing cart items end
        state.loading = false;
    }
```